# kendo Datepicker: Prevent closing picker when clicking a date

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

When I change the date in the picker then the picker is getting hidden, How can skip this behavior in kendo ui datePicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the change method for the date picker's DateView so that it doesn't close the popup:

```
var datePicker = $("#sampleDate").kendoDatePicker({}).getKendoDatePicker();

datePicker.dateView.options.change = function () {
    datePicker._change(this.value());
};
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/E5M4d/1/))

Comment: nice solution, don't really know how it works haha. Any idea of how it can be done with a regular `@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()`?

Comment: @CSharper you can only change those internals with JS; the problem is that you don't know when the Kendo controls have finished loading (at least I'm not aware if there's a way) so you can change the widget; I guess you could use the date picker's open event and change this.dateView.options.change in the same way whenever the picker is opened

Comment: @CSharper actually, you can use the same code, just put it in a jQuery ready block and place that after the  code that initializes your date picker

Answer (score 2):

Simply do `e.preventDefault()` on the close event.

```js
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    close: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent popup closing
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexyu/Yz5sQ/)

However, you will no longer be able to close the datepicker in any way, so make sure you prevent default only when you want to keep the datepicker open.

e.g

```
close: function(e) {
    if(keepOpen === true){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture the change event of the datePicker

```
 $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker()
      .Events(e =>
      {
          e.Change("JSFunction");
      })


function JSFunction() {
   var datepicker = $("#datePickerId").data("kendoDatePicker");
    datepicker.open();
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried the above, but it still closing the the picker once user changes the date.